# How to plot triple-nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Edit for info:
I'm accessing the NHL's API to get event-related stats for single games. I have a clean pd.dataframe containing the info and variables I need. I have done quite a lot of wrangling/cleaning to get here and am unsure wether it would be useful/how to share all of the steps efficiently. I then made nested dictionaries to get counts for shots and goals divided by shot type and distance from the net.
This is how I created the dictionaries:

```
keys0 = list(test['Dist_cat'].unique())
keys0.sort()
#keys0 = [0-10, 10-20, 20-30, 30-40, 40-50, 60+]
keys1 = ['Goal','Shot' ,'Percentage']
keys2 = ['Wrist Shot', 'Slap Shot','Snap Shot' ,'Backhand', 'Tip-In', 'Deflected', 'Wrap-around']

data = dict()
for key0 in keys0:
    data[key0] = dict()
    for key1 in keys1:
        data[key0][key1] = dict()
        for key2 in keys2:
            data[key0][key1][key2] = (test['Dist_cat'] == key0) & (test['shot_type'] == key2) & (test['result_event'] == key1)

count_dict = dict()
for key0 in keys0:
    count_dict[key0] = dict()
    for key1 in keys1:
        count_dict[key0][key1] = dict()
        for key2 in keys2:
            if key1 == 'Percentage':
                
                count_dict[key0][key1][key2] = 100*(count_dict[key0]['Goal'][key2].values/(count_dict[key0]['Shot'][key2].values+count_dict[key0]['Goal'][key2].values))
            else:
                count_dict[key0][key1][key2] = (test[data[key0][key1][key2]]['result_event'].value_counts())

count_dict = pd.DataFrame(count_dict)
print(count_dict)
```

So I have triple-nested dictionaries with hockey stats (from inside out I have: types of shots (wrist, slap, etc); goals, missed shots (simply labeled 'shots') and goal%; distance from net (0-10, 10-20, 20-30,...). There are 7 types of shots, including wrist, slap, snap, backhand, tip-in, deflected and wrap-around.

```
0-10  \
Goal        {'Wrist Shot': [585], 'Slap Shot': [12], 'Snap...   
Shot        {'Wrist Shot': [2357], 'Slap Shot': [76], 'Sna...   
Percentage  {'Wrist Shot': [0.19884432358939497], 'Slap Sh...   

10-20  \
Goal        {'Wrist Shot': [1534], 'Slap Shot': [60], 'Sna...   
Shot        {'Wrist Shot': [7834], 'Slap Shot': [201], 'Sn...   
Percentage  {'Wrist Shot': [0.16374893253629377], 'Slap Sh...   

20-30  \
Goal        {'Wrist Shot': [997], 'Slap Shot': [100], 'Sna...   
Shot        {'Wrist Shot': [7466], 'Slap Shot': [580], 'Sn...   
Percentage  {'Wrist Shot': [0.11780692425853716], 'Slap Sh...   

30-40  \
Goal        {'Wrist Shot': [610], 'Slap Shot': [202], 'Sna...   
Shot        {'Wrist Shot': [8336], 'Slap Shot': [1482], 'S...   
Percentage  {'Wrist Shot': [0.06818689917281466], 'Slap Sh...   

40-60  \
Goal        {'Wrist Shot': [452], 'Slap Shot': [362], 'Sna...   
Shot        {'Wrist Shot': [12901], 'Slap Shot': [6911], '...   
Percentage  {'Wrist Shot': [0.033850071145061035], 'Slap S...   

60+  
Goal        {'Wrist Shot': [149], 'Slap Shot': [47], 'Snap...  
Shot        {'Wrist Shot': [4422], 'Slap Shot': [2215], 'S...  
Percentage  {'Wrist Shot': [0.03259680595055787], 'Slap Sh...
```

I'm trying to create a plot that looks something like [this image i found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svu5G.png)

To be clear, I'm trying to communicate goal percentage as a function of both distance to the net and shot type category.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
It's also best to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to enable others to help you.
That also shows what you have done so far and at which specific problem you are stuck.

Comment: can you provide the dataframe?